# Tooltip doesn't show properly in highcharts

Tags: charts, tooltip, highcharts, diagram

I want to draw a diagram like this in highcharts:
[image]

The diagram itself doesn't have any problem. But whenever I try to hover on any point in the diagram it doesn't render properly. You can see the live example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xS8xb/

I know that it's not a regular chart and mathematically a function. But is there any hack to solve this problem?

Comment: To share my knowledge this kind of problems with tooltip occurs whenever the data is not bound in order increasing or decreasing. And you can't give data in order for the shape... hmmm...

Comment: I had the same problem, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069809/hover-markers-missing-on-disconnected-graph

Answer (score 2):

Caution, extreme hackery ahead:
You can create more than one series on a chart so you could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CQxdt/). Using 2 series. Of course the curves are not properly matched but it gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

*The diagram itself doesn't have any problem*

Actually it does, as you have set the value x=10 two times. Therefore, it's not mathematically a function and this maybe is preventing it to render the tooltips correctly. I changed it and the tooltips seem to work fine (displaying the following information: 'Tokio', y-value in bold and x-value at the top). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xS8xb/1/)

Comment: I knew that! I need to draw a diagram exactly like the diagram I mentioned above. Is there any hack to handle this?