# Hover markers missing on disconnected graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm facing a problem and I am not sure if it's a bug in the highcharts  plugin or a programing error.

I am using null values to draw a disconnected line graph with only one serie but it seems to be a problem with the hover markers : some of them (on the top of the first line and bottom of the second) just seem to not appear. The code is simple but i can't find what would cause this.

Here is an exemple reproducing the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/KYXQS/9/ (updated 26/02)

And here the code (updated 26/02) :

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        plotOptions :
        {
            line : {
                marker :
                {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Red',
            data: [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[2,0],[3,1],[4,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[6,4],[7,5],[8,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[12,0],[13,1],[14,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[16,4],[17,5],[18,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[22,0],[23,1],[24,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[26,4],[27,5],[28,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[32,0],[33,1],[34,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[36,4],[37,5],[38,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[34,0],[35,1],[36,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[38,4],[39,5],[40,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[36,0],[37,1],[38,2]
                   ,null
                   ,[40,4],[41,5],[42,6]

                   ,null
                   ,[40,2],[41,2],[42,3]
                   ,null
                   ,[47,8],[48,10],[49,11]
                  ],
            color: 'red'
        }
        ,{
            name: 'Blue',
            data: [[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[8,8],[9,10],[10,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[4,2],[5,3],[6,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[10,8],[11,10],[12,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[14,2],[15,3],[16,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[20,8],[21,10],[22,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[24,2],[25,3],[26,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[30,8],[31,10],[32,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[34,2],[35,3],[36,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[40,8],[41,10],[42,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[36,2],[37,3],[38,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[42,8],[43,10],[44,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[38,2],[39,3],[40,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[44,8],[45,10],[46,12]

                   ,null
                   ,[42,3],[41,3],[42,4]
                   ,null
                   ,[49,11],[52,12],[53,12]
                  ],
            color: 'blue'
        }
        ,{
            name: 'Green',
            data: [[6,6],[7,7],[8,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[10,12],[11,15],[12,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[8,6],[9,7],[10,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[12,12],[13,15],[14,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[8,6],[9,7],[10,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[12,12],[13,15],[14,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[18,6],[19,7],[20,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[22,12],[23,15],[24,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[28,6],[29,7],[30,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[32,12],[33,15],[34,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[38,6],[39,7],[40,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[42,12],[43,15],[44,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[40,6],[41,7],[42,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[44,12],[45,15],[46,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[42,6],[43,7],[44,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[46,12],[47,15],[48,19]

                   ,null
                   ,[42,4],[45,5],[47,8]
                   ,null
                   ,[53,12],[54,13],[55,14]
                  ],
            color: 'green'
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Any idea on how to make those markers reappear ?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 26/02 :
I've been testing other scenarios to identify the cause of this problem and here is what i found out :
- The problem occurs when lines are too close to each other (on the xAxis)
- Zoom doesn't help,  even full zoomed on the place where the marker is supposed to appear does not make it appear.
- The problem occurs whenever the y values are the same or not

UPDATE 25/04 :
For an example you can see the bug when trying to hover the point at [47,15] on the green series. Instead of the [47,15] point it is the [47,8] point that is "hovered" and whatever I try (like zooming exactly on it) I just can't "hover" the [47,15] point.

I've updated the jsfiddle link and the code above with more exemple to illustrate the problem.

Anyone have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: It's actually the whole top half of the first line plotted that doesn't work. Have you tried removing the other co-ordinates and simply plotting just one line for now. Making sure that works, before you move onto two?

Comment: Yes and it works fine with only one line. The problem comes when you add the second line by using the 'null value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in Highcharts data for one series should be sorted ascending for xAxis, while your series aren't. Sort your data, and should be working.

Comment: You are probably right about the origin of the bug but unfortunatly sorting the data is not an option, it would completly change the aspect of the chart since the data is separated by "null" values to draw separated segments with a single series. For a simplier example, this is what it have to look like http://jsfiddle.net/6jdMZ/ (you can notice the bug on the higher points), with sorted data it would look like this http://jsfiddle.net/6jdMZ/1/ try to hover the point at [6,4], it is impossible. It's certainly a good lead, but is there a workaround that keep the aspect of the chart ?

Comment: You still can split that one series into three different, all linked to one legend item, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/6jdMZ/3/ linkedTo was introduced in 3.0 version

Comment: I implemented this to my project and it works great ! Thanks a lot for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you aren't actually talking about markers since those are set to

plotOptions :
        {
            line : {
                marker :
                {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        },

in your example.  If you want to show markers you will need to change that to enabled: true.

You are probably talking about the tooltip instead.

What you need to do is change your code to:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
            s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + 'm';
        });

        return s;
    },
},
```

See these doc entries and fiddles:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-shared/

Comment: Thank for your response, but that's not what I'm exactly looking for.

It is really markers that are the problem here. If you look at the jsfiddle i posted (http://jsfiddle.net/KYXQS/1/) you will notice that markers are indeed disabled but hover markers are still enabled (so as tooltip).

So, the issue here is that not ALL hover markers seem to work, particulary at the top of the first line. And I'm wondering what could cause those marker to not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Bug is neither in highcharts and nor in your program. Problem is that some of the markers are hidden behind others. 
Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/KYXQS/10/
You will notice that at the connection point of green and blue lines, blue markers are hidden behind green ones. Try deselecting green series from legend and hidden blue markers will show up.

Enable markers in chart options like this:

```
           line : {
                marker :
                {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem here. The bug is that some tooltip on hover markers does not appear.

For a clearer example on JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/KYXQS/10/
Try hovering the markers on the green series at approximatly x = 45 and y = 15. You will notice that the tooltip shown and the "hovered marker" (on hover size of the marker is bigger) isn't the correct one.

Pardon me if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yes I get your point and see the problem. I too agree with Pawel's solution that all points in a series should be sorted according to x-axis. But in your case sorting isn't an option. So, using multiple series, each with sorted x coordinates, all of them with same color and n-1 series "linkedTo" last one series should solve the problem perfectly.